# I have an issue debugging a program in C on Atom text editor with the dbg-gdb package. The debugger does not halt at the breakpoint

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, atom-editor

I am using the Atom editor to debug a C program. I have downloaded the package dgb-gdb that I found [here](https://github.com/31i73/atom-dbg-gdb) and I followed the instructions to activate it. However, when I set the breakpoint and then press F5 to run and debug, the debugger does not halt at the breakpoint and the program is executed as usual, [as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcDC6.png). Actually, if I run without the breakpoint the debug interface is shown for just a millisecond and then shuts down without leaving any error message. When I toggle the breakpoint instead, the behavior is the one already mentioned.

I am almost certain that the gdb debugger works because I can perform the debug session from the cmd prompt correctly. The problem arises when I try to use the interface provided by the package.
Do you have any idea of what is going on?